# Cannot get past passing an object to MediatR query

Tags: c#, mediator, mediatr

I am trying to use the Mediator (using MediatR) query pattern. I need to pass in my user object.

Here is my query:

```
public class GetAllInvoicesQuery : IRequest<IEnumerable<OrderDto>>
{
    public class GetAllInvoicesQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetAllInvoicesQuery, IEnumerable<OrderDto>>
    {
        private readonly IEntityContext _context;

        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public User User { get; set; }

        public GetAllInvoicesQueryHandler(IEntityContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<OrderDto>> Handle(GetAllInvoicesQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var invoices = await _context.Orders
                .Include(d => d.Details)
                .Include(r => r.ReservedDocument)
                .Include(b => b.Billto)
                .Include(s => s.Shipto)
                .OrderByDescending(d => d.Docdate)
                .Where(x => x.Soptype == OrderType.Invoice && x.Custnmbr == User.Custnmbr)
                .ProjectTo<OrderDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

            if (invoices.Count == 0)
                return null;

            return invoices.AsReadOnly();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my controler action:

```
[HttpGet("GetAllInvoices")]
[Authorize]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesDefaultResponseType]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllInvoicesAsync()
{
    HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("User", out var user);

    if (user is null)
    {
        _logger.ForContext<UsersController>().Debug("User is null");
        return BadRequest(new { message = "Can't find user." });
    }

    return Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GetAllInvoicesQuery { User = (User)user } ));
                                                            ^^^^
}
```

Visual Studio is complaining about my `User`, it says it "cannot resolve symbol User" in the return line of the controller action. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Visual studio does not complain, it merely tells you facts as best it can, as such, it cant identify what `User` is... Why do you suspect (or leads to believe) there is a property called `User` in `GetAllInvoicesQuery` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` Property needs to be on the `GetAllInvoicesQuery` class, not the `GetAllInvoicesQueryHandler` class.

Comment: I moved it to the `GetAllInvoicesQuery ` class now my controller can see it. However, in `GetAllInvoicesQueryHandler ` VS says it can't access Non static property.

Comment: O.K. I changed my reference from `User.Custnmbr` to `query.User.Custnmbr` and it all works. Thanks.